# Is there any reason why preventing Disposable Email Address used to sign up?

Tags: manual-testing, email, security

I've been tested some of websites and apps, and I noticed that some of them preventing user to Sign Up using [Disposable Email Address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disposable_email_address)

First things come to my head, this can be used to join an event where new user will get a chance to win a prize, so user can abuse it by Sign Up as much as they want, or maybe access free Trial on new user.

I'm curious is there any other reason behind this?

Answer (score 2):

Disposable email address cannot be easily tracked. Also, this can be used for fraudulent access to sites which require email authentication. It can also be used to post explicit content on sites and 'disappear' after posting so that the perpetrator cannot be tracked. There are many other reasons why disposable email addresses are not encouraged. Hope this clarifies; again the uses are many depending on what you are looking for.

Cheers!